# How to record the sound playing in headset using ffmpeg

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, audio

I'm trying to record screen and input/output audio on a headset but its recording only audio from headset microphone. How can I record the sound I'm hearing through headset

```
ffmpeg -y  -f gdigrab -framerate ntsc -i desktop  -f dshow -i audio="Headset Microphone (Plantronics C320-M)" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast "video output.mp4"
```

I tried setting audio="Stereo Mix (Conexant ISST Audio)" its recording computer audio but when I connect USB headset its not recording anything. I'm seeing the following devices when I run the below command

`ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy`

1. Headset Microphone (Plantronics C320-M)
2. Stereo Mix (Conexant ISST Audio)
3. Internal Microphone (Conexant ISST Audio)

Answer (score 1):

for the headset, try to use 3.5mm jack to connect to the pc instead of USB.
It works fine for me:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -rtbufsize 512M -f dshow -i audio="Stereo Mix (Realtek(R) Audio)" -f dshow -i audio="External Microphone (Realtek(R) Audio)" -f gdigrab -framerate 60 -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size 1920x1080 -draw_mouse 1 -i desktop -c:v hevc -filter_complex amerge=inputs=2 -ac 2 -y recording.mkv
```